# How can i show past Data on my Flaskr/Javascript chart?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, charts

I'm building a Flaskr webapp. From my Flask backend i'm sending some data which is displayed on the webpage with a Javascript frontend. The data is sent through SocketIO.

I added a chart to display this data, but the problem is that the chart will reset each time the page is opened. So when i open the webpage i should be able to see what the chart looked like before i opened it. Shortly, it should have historical data, other than real-time data.

I know that i should look for a way to store this data, but i'm fairly new to this and i can't find a workaround for this. Could someone please help me?

This is what the Flask client looks like:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, copy_current_request_context
from random import random
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event


__author__ = 'slynn'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

#turn the flask app into a socketio app
socketio = SocketIO(app)

#random number Generator Thread
thread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()


class RandomThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 1
        super(RandomThread, self).__init__()

    def randomNumberGenerator(self):
        """
        Generate a random number every 1 second and emit to a socketio instance (broadcast)
        Ideally to be run in a separate thread?
        """
        #infinite loop of magical random numbers
        print("Making random numbers")
        while not thread_stop_event.isSet():
            number = round(random()*10, 3)
            print(number)
            socketio.emit('newnumber', {'number': number}, namespace='/test')
            sleep(self.delay)

    def run(self):
        self.randomNumberGenerator()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    #only by sending this page first will the client be connected to the socketio instance
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    # need visibility of the global thread object
    global thread
    print('Client connected')

    #Start the random number generator thread only if the thread has not been started before.
    if not thread.isAlive():
        print("Starting Thread")
        thread = RandomThread()
        thread.start()

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')





if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

And this is what the Javascript/Chart part looks like:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
  //connect to the socket server.
  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
  var numbers_received = [];


  //receive details from server
  socket.on('newnumber', function(msg) {
    console.log("Received" + msg.number);
    //maintain a list of ten numbers
    if (numbers_received.length >= 1) {
      numbers_received.shift()
    }


    numbers_received.push(msg.number);
    numbers_string = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers_received.length; i++) {
      numbers_string = numbers_string + '<p>' + numbers_received[i].toString() + '</p>';
    }
    $('#log').html(numbers_string);
  });



  function getData() {


    }
    Plotly.plot('chart',[{
        y:[numbers_received[1]],
        type:'line'
        }]);

        console.log('TEST' + numbers_received[0]);

        var cnt = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
        Plotly.extendTraces('chart',{ y:[[numbers_received[0]]]}, [0]);

        cnt++;

        if(cnt >10000000) {
            Plotly.relayout('chart',{
                xaxis: {
                    range: [cnt-9,cnt]
                    }
                });
            }
    },15);

});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/application.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Asynchronous Flask Communication</h1>
    <p>Random numbers generated by the Flask server will appear below, asynchronously.</p>
    <p>Details <a href='https://www.shanelynn.ie/asynchronous-updates-to-a-webpage-with-flask-and-socket-io/' target='_blank'>here.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Asynchronous page updates will appear here:</p>
        <h3>Number list:</h3>
        <div id="log">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="chart"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share full code in order to simulate the case and provide a better answer?

Comment: Of course, just give me a sec to edit it

Comment: Here you go! I updated it. This is where i took the code https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask (basically instead of the random number which is just a test, i will add my own data fetched from an API and add some DBs)

Comment: got it! I drafted an idea below and I will try to implement it on your code

Comment: looking forward to it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with passing only one number and without using central sync is that by the moment you receive old history and process it already the API has generated new numbers, So the true task is how to sync the current state or number with the previously generated ones in real time even if you manage to pass history.

Current situation:

- you start generating random numbers from the moment the API became
  alive.
- a client gets the live feed the moment it connects with the API through socket and then reads the feed from the current number and
  until it disconnects.
- previously generated numbers are not given/provided to any client.
- also if a client connects reads for some time closes and then connects again, its starts plotting from that current point and on.

Under this situation your need is to have the clients get all the previously generated numbers and plot them before they start reading the current ones being generated.

The technical difficulties it posses:

- the solution should sync mid way, while the clients receives the old
  data through a JSON or something else, you still have to align after
  the plotting and perform again and again a sync function until it
  reaches same level as the current number being generated.
- you have to manage in a way both previous and currently generated feed for all clients (unless in theory one is connected as soon as
  the API starts and gets the feed from the first one).

Possible, theoretical solutions to you problem are not only real time tools like https://www.rethinkdb.com/, but also concepts of data `at-rest` for the previously generated numbers. So again, in theory you'd have to call a recursive function to:

- on each generated number you can assign the timestamp in order to compare with current or the ones you have and know if it is the higher or lower.
- plot the old data collected and stored into the server and feed at initial connection.
- plot the data generated while you where plotting the oldest one (these batch is generated by the moment you connected until the moment you finished the old ones)
- plot the data generated during the second plotting.
- check if you reached current head.
- repeat || if head then continue plotting only the latest.
- the function that plots should be able to process a list or a single number thus supporting on both cases, when behind and when it receives a single one.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. Sorry if i say something stupid, but i'm fairly newbie to this! I know what a linked list is (studied it on C), and it could work, but one of my concerns is: consider that i will be loading a page, the chart will have to load all those data points from the array. What happens when the chart has to load a lot of data points from a large array? Would the page become slow or crash?

Comment: at some point yes, especially over network resource since you will be consuming them for each concurrent user that will be requesting the data from the server. To be more efficient you have to introduce data storage on user's side which means that you are either using a local DB on the user's side or a local file where you append the results through the socket and have another function reading it. A purely and very elegant DB for real time web is this https://www.rethinkdb.com/ ;)

Comment: Yes, i made some research a while ago and i found rethinkdb, the only thing that stopped me was finding that the project shut down, i don't know at what point it is right now though

Comment: @Jack022 sorry mate, I try to implement the solution and I went until the first cycle but the graph  felt short of the currently new ones and while plotted the old ones it was missing the ones being generated at the time of plotting of the old. In the answer I explained in detail the situation ;)

Comment: Hey! Thank you! Maybe i should try to learn some more programming, i thought it would be easier when i started this project weeks ago but at this point i think it became too "advanced" for me. Thanks again for helping, i never got any answer until now here :)

Comment: don't mention it! I hope you enjoy it because real-time is one of my favorite topics :)

Comment: Yeah, i even thought of building the whole thing using Dash but it felt a little off, since i already started with "my own way" (Flaskr + SocketIO)

Comment: @Jack022 I believe there is also another point of view.... I shared the idea with my team, and one of my colleagues 'ethimjosvelo' on SO, said an interesting point, and there is something that can be done.... look at this flow:

- run the API
- append() all number into a list
- when a client connects into the service then start getting the new numbers immediately and plot on them and on.
- at the connection level also retrieve a list of all the previous once and from here I am thinking a way to show them on the graph before plotting the new ones, or even have a function to combine them

Comment: this way in stand of focusing into syncing with the new ones we guarantee that all the new ones will be read and the tough part is only to merge the old ones with the graph :) is like solving the other way around

Comment: This looks like a good idea @oetoni, i'm going to take some time to see if i can implement it!

Comment: By the way i'm looking more into RethinkDB and it definitely is something i need

Comment: if you don't manage to solve until Friday, I will try to find some spare time tomorrow or the day after and finish the code as per description above and post an update.

Comment: Thank you once again, i'll let you know here!

Comment: Maybe another solution would be to generate the chart from my Backend. But since my backend is Python, i'd need a Python charting library which works well with web pages

Comment: At the end, tried pretty much everything, included with SocketIO from my Flask backend, where i was sending the data through socketio, but it didn't work either

Comment: Hi @Jack022, allow me to try one last atempt over the weekend (because I have some time, and post back here) ;) until yesterday I had heavy tasks in office

Comment: Hey, don't worry mate! Hope you'll have a wonderful weekend and don't forget to get some rest from your tasks :)